# iOS 10 interactive notifications not working on app made in iOS 9

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10

I observed that interactive notifications are not working on older devices for iOS 10. My app had functionality to show "Yes","No" buttons when notification is swiped left. I see that this doesn't work on iOS 10. Only way to see the buttons is by 3d touch.

I also read this is possible using the new frameworks which apple has introduced in iOS 10. For now, I don't have time to go through the framework and write new code as my release date is very near.

Is using the new frameworks the only way to support interactive notifications on iOS 10?

Comment: Please fix the title.  It doesn't seem to match your question.  Is it older app on iOS 10, iOS 10 SDK app on older iOS versions, or something else?

Comment: @Avi Changed. Does it make simpler to understand my issue now?

Comment: @matt I am compiling against iOS 10. I just wanted to be 100% sure if interactive notifications will work without the new framework in iOS 10.

Comment: A deprecation notice is a warning, not a command.  But your advice to compile against a pre-10 SDK is spot-on.

Comment: You can solve it by this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10

Comment: i too have same problem ,notification actions are missing in iOS 10 devices. Only textInput is working.

Comment: @Alok did you find solutions?

Comment: @Madhu did you find solutions?

Comment: yes, i have added the actions for iOS 10 notifications using UNNotificationAction. Need to update app in store again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in ios 10. So you need to implement instead of "UIUserNotification" to "UNNotification" to work in ios 10 use this

`UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
| UNAuthorizationOptionSound
| UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}
];`